# Exported data from Octopus Deploy 3.9 and now having issues importing Octopus Deploy 4.10?

Tags: import, octopus-deploy

I exported data from Octopus Deploy 3.9 from one server and tried to import into Octopus 4.10 on another server?

Getting the following errors:

> Error: Directory does not contain an Octopus export
>
> Error: The previous command returned a non-zero exit code of: 1
>
> Error: The command that failed was: "F:\Program Files\Octopus Deploy
>   4.1\Octopus.Migrator.exe" import --instance "OctopusServer" --directory "F:\Octopus\OctopusData\Events" --password "afs1"

Other Details:

Octopus Deploy 3.9 was installed on C:\ on one server

Octopus Deploy 4.1 was installed on E:\ on another

Logs:

```
2018-02-02 13:46:12.3847   6820      1  INFO  Environment Information:
  OperatingSystem: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
  OsBitVersion: x64
  Is64BitProcess: True
  CurrentUser: AFSDEV\cgarcia
  MachineName: AFS-SBX-TFS
  ProcessorCount: 4
  CurrentDirectory: F:\Program Files\Octopus Deploy 4.1
  TempDirectory: C:\Users\cgarcia\AppData\Local\Temp\
  HostProcessName: Octopus.Migrator
  PID: 6820
2018-02-02 13:46:12.4784   6820      1  INFO  ==== ImportFilesCommand ====
2018-02-02 13:46:12.4940   6820      1 FATAL  Directory does not contain an Octopus export
```

Comment: I don't think importing on a different version of Octopus is supported.  I have not had any luck doing that either.

Comment: Turns out Mike is correct, they need to be the same version.